# Apply function to each element in range

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Using Microsoft Excel 2010, if have a range (in my case, a name defined as `OFFSET(A!$A$10,0,1,1,B!$J$4)`) that I'm using as chart series values, how can I apply a function to transform this range, multiplying each element by `-1`?

I would like to "flip" the range's values on my chart without having to manually write out a table to transform the values one by one:

[image: Sample data]

The ultimate goal is to display the red series in the positive area, along with the blue and green series, even though the red series data is negative. I would like to do this in the most simple way possible, preferably by simply applying a function to the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your named range

```
=-OFFSET(A!$A$10,0,1,1,B!$J$4)
```

Comment: Hah! That actually works. So how come I can't write `=-NamedRange`?

Comment: Being able to apply this sort of logic to named ranges would be _very_ useful, so that I don't have to keep duplicating my named ranges every time I want to add some petty manipulation, like `* -1` or `* 12`.

Comment: It has something to do with the SERIES function, but I don't know what exactly.  I agree it would be nice.  One thing you can do is base one name on another.  Create a name called rSeries.  Then create rSeriesNeg with a RefersTo of -rSeries.  It's still more names to manage, but now if you change rSeries, rSeriesNeg is automatically updated.

Comment: Aha, that's good. So at this point the only thing missing is to be able to apply this logic directly as a series function, without requiring an interim name. Thanks!